# Remove null entry from custom list in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a custom list as below

```
[Application(bname=null, cid=null, fname=“abc”)]
```

Now I need to set the values to another list but I have to remove null values i.e. bname=null so I don't want to set it to the second list

I have written below the code

```
Obj.setApplication(list.getApplication().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Could you please help to correct the above code block?

Comment: you might be looking to filter based on the attribute being null i.e. `filter(app -> app.getBName() !=null)`